# Frequency Plot in R for example dataset

Tags: r, bar-chart, rscript

I had the Dataset like

```
Name,School,Grade,Hobby,Addr1,Addr2,State
Sanjay1,BiharSchool1,11,"Cricket,Hockey,Badminton",xxxx,India,Bihar
Sanjay2,UpSchool1,11,"Volleyball,Hockey,Football",xxxx,India,UP
Sanjay3,BiharSchool2,11,"Boxing",xxxx,India,Bihar
Sanjay4,MPSchool1,11,"Cricket,Hockey,Badminton",xxxx,India,MP
Sanjay5,BiharSchool3,11,"Boxing",xxxx,India,Bihar
Sanjay6,MPSchool1,11,"Cricket,Hockey,Badminton",xxxx,India,MP
```

Is there way I can create Chart for the following requirements

1. Show State Name and Different Number of School Frequency. Like Above shows Bihar State has 3 different School, UP & MP has one school ( Even MP has two record but School name is same)
2. Show Hobbies Frequency like Cricket- 3times, Hockey-4 times, Boxing-2 times and so on

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### 1.a Bar plot of `School` counts by `State`

Separate the rows by `Hobby`, and count the needed occurrences. Then pipe to a bar plot.

```r
x <- '
Name,School,Grade,Hobby,Addr1,Addr2,State
Sanjay1,BiharSchool1,11,"Cricket,Hockey,Badminton",xxxx,India,Bihar
Sanjay2,UpSchool1,11,"Volleyball,Hockey,Football",xxxx,India,UP
Sanjay3,BiharSchool2,11,"Boxing",xxxx,India,Bihar
Sanjay4,MPSchool1,11,"Cricket,Hockey,Badminton",xxxx,India,MP
Sanjay5,BiharSchool3,11,"Boxing",xxxx,India,Bihar
Sanjay6,MPSchool1,11,"Cricket,Hockey,Badminton",xxxx,India,MP'
df1 <- read.csv(textConnection(x))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(Hobby) %>%
  count(State, School) %>%
  ggplot(aes(State, n, fill = School)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### 1.b Count of `School` by `State`

```r
df1 %>%
  count(State, name = "School") %>%
  ggplot(aes(State, School)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue2", position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### 2. Bar plot of `Hobby`

The same as above, separate the rows by `Hobby`, then compute the rows hobbies frequencies. And pipe to a bar chart.

```r
df1 %>%
  separate_rows(Hobby) %>%
  count(Hobby) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Hobby, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue2", position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Rui, It is perfect. Can you help in First Group as I want to show Bihar Showing Frequency 3, UP and MP with Frequency One. Don't need to show Name of School but only count of different school in each State

Comment: @Sajaym Done, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks Rui for your time and quick solution which also help me to dig better for more reports.